# Change Joda DateTime timezone but don't change time

Tags: android, datetime, jodatime

I am using (maybe incorrectly) a Joda DateTime to store a reminder time in a reminders app. When the timezone changes on the device (because of DST or just moving to a different TZ) I want to be able to reset the reminders to use the current timezone but keep the time.

For example: I set a reminder for Friday May 15th, at 15:00. If the timezone changes before that time, I want to be able to recreate the reminder for Friday May 15th at 15:00 local time.

I have already tried to use withZoneRetainFields but I haven't been able to keep the time unchanged:

```
new DateTime(reminderTimeMillis, DateTimeZone.forID(previousTimeZone)).withZoneRetainFields(DateTimeZone.getDefault())
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that method should basically work:

```
@Test
public void change_timezone_of_reminder() {
    DateTime originalReminderDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2015-05-15T15:00").toDateTime(
            DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Berlin"));
    assertThat(originalReminderDateTime.toString(), equalTo("2015-05-15T15:00:00.000+02:00"));
    long reminderMillis = originalReminderDateTime.getMillis();
    DateTime updatedTime = new DateTime(reminderMillis, DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Berlin"))
            .withZoneRetainFields(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York"));
    assertThat(updatedTime.toLocalDateTime(), equalTo(LocalDateTime.parse("2015-05-15T15:00")));
    assertThat(updatedTime.toString(), equalTo("2015-05-15T15:00:00.000-04:00"));
}
```

So, how are you evaluating that the time field is not changing?

Also, if you are storing the reminder time as millis-after-epoch, you don't need to adjust it for DST shifts, if you're calculating the millis using a full timezone ("Europe/Berlin") rather than a fixed offset.